# Error with Installing Red5

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, red5

I have tried to install Red5 on Ubuntu. Now, I have followed the instructions [here](http://labs.distriqt.com/post/493), but the build failed.

What's the problem?

Screenshot of the console is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMgC5.png)

I have tried to Google it, but i can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and installing sysout-over-slf4j and making sure it's in your java class path:

http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/quickstart.html

Comment: I have read it. But it doesn't tell me where to put the dependency. Also how do I put it in the class path? I'm quite new to this.